# Equivalent of BufferedImage from Java to C#

Tags: c#, java, .net, syntax

I am trying to convert a Java program to C# and I don't know the equivalent of BufferedImage from Java to C#...

Code from Java:

```
public static String ActiveContour(int x11, int x22, int y11, int y22, BufferedImage bufIm, int contor)
{

double [][] img=new double[bufIm.getHeight()][bufIm.getWidth()];
double [][] imgf=new double[bufIm.getHeight()][bufIm.getWidth()];

w=bufIm.getWidth();
h=bufIm.getHeight();

for(int i=0;i<h;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<w;j++)
    {
       img[i][j]=bufIm.getRGB(j, i);
       c = new Color((int)img[i][j]);
       img[i][j]= 0.2898*c.getRed() + 0.5870*c.getGreen() + 0.1140*c.getBlue(); 
    }
```

Am I missing a statement?

```
using System...;
```

because in Java I have

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
```

Answer (score 6):

`System.Drawing.Bitmap` is the closest I can think of.

Comment: @Bosco do you have a reference to `System.Drawing.dll`? (note you shouldn't use this from a web app)

Answer (score 1):

What does this function do? Why bother with translating the code bit by bit when most probably there is another way achieving the same result using C# classes?  In C# using System.Drawing.Bitmap is common practice but there are other ways depending on what the code is meant to be doing.